# Prefix operators are not working as expected in C

Tags: c, postfix-operator, logical-or, prefix-operator, logical-and

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a = 1;
    int b = 1;
    int c = a || --b;
    int d = a-- && --b;
    printf("a=%d, b= %d, c= %d, d= %d",a,b,c,d);
    return 0;
}
```

In th above code, I expected output to be `a=0, b= -1, c= 1, d= 0` but the output was `a=0, b= 0, c= 1, d= 0`

[Screenshot_VS Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LxPyX.png)

Comment: Don't code that way. Such code is unreadable, and you will be in trouble understanding it the next month. Consider using [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) as `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` to compile your code, and also use [the clang static analyzer](https://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/) on your code

Comment: Please do not add pictures of your code or your output if it is only plain text.

Comment: There is no [tag:postfix-notation] here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the expression used as an initializer in this declaration

```
int c = a || --b;
```

as the operand `a` is not equal to 0 then the expression `--b` is not evaluated.

So the variable `c` is initialized by `1`.

From the C Standard (6.5.14 Logical OR operator)

> 4 Unlike the bitwise | operator, the || operator guarantees
> left-to-right evaluation; if the second operand is evaluated, there is
> a sequence point between the evaluations of the first and second
> operands. **If the first operand compares unequal to 0, the second
> operand is not evaluated.**

In the expression used as an initializer in this declaration

```
int d = a-- && --b;
```

the operand `a--` is not equal to 0 (the value of the postfix operator is the value of its operand before decrementing). So the operand `--b` is evaluated.
As its value is equal to `0` then the variable `d` is initialized by `0`.

From the C Standard (6.5.13 Logical AND operator)

> 4 Unlike the bitwise binary & operator, the && operator guarantees
> left-to-right evaluation; if the second operand is evaluated, there is
> a sequence point between the evaluations of the first and second
> operands. **If the first operand compares equal to 0, the second
> operand is not evaluated**.

As a result `a` and `b` will be equal 0 after this declaration.